# Override theme programmatically

Tags: theme-development, themes

Is it possible to override the theme, programmatically, for a WordPress site? I have a site I’ve been developing and want to test it on my client’s site before flipping the switch. What I’d like to do is override the theme based on my IP address. In pseudo code, something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'my.ip') {
    set_theme_to('new-theme-name');
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `switch_theme` function.

> Accepts one argument: $stylesheet of the theme. ($stylesheet is the name of your folder slug. It's the same value that you'd use for a child theme, something like "twentythirteen".)

Documentation: [switch_theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme)

Comment: Will that “persist” the theme for subsequent requests (like changing theme in WP-Admin)? Or will it change the theme for the current request only?

Comment: Probably this will change theme for entire page. You need to load whole theme for selected users or load different css files will be enough?

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong! Calling switch_theme() updates the active theme in the site's configuration. The question is explicitly asking to avoid such side effects.